# Add prefix and suffix to every line in RTB Visual Studio 2013

Tags: css, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, fonts

I am having difficulty adding a prefix and suffix to my text in RichTextBox Visual Studio.

Currently I am having a code like this

```
TextBox1.Text = "<font face='Calibir' size =1 color=#444444>" + TextBox2.Text + "</font>"
```

But now my boss requires to add `<font>` tag to every line in my Text Box so the output will be as follows in the TextBox1

```
<font face='Calibir' size =1 color=#444444>Line1</font>
<font face='Calibir' size =1 color=#444444>Line2</font>
<font face='Calibir' size =1 color=#444444>Line3</font>
<font face='Calibir' size =1 color=#444444>Line4</font>
```

I don't know why he is doing that but he needs in the above way only.

Plz Help!!

Comment: Maybe you should tell your boss `<font>` has been deprecated for fifteen years now.

Comment: Yeah..but his Tool to upload the data needs those tags...

Comment: Sounds like his tool needs rewriting, not the code on your end.